# MD5 Hashes not matching

Tags: php, sql, md5

I am trying to match a md5 has (generated through php) to its original value in a SQLExpress database.

I am using the following function in my SQL query

```
master.sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HASHBYTES('MD5', 'ID'), 1, 0)
```

Where 'ID' is the field in the database.

However they both seem to return different values for the md5 hash. I have been using '12290' as a static value to test this.

php md5() returns: 0bd81786a8ec6ae9b22cbb3cb4d88179

The following SQL Statement returns the same output:

```
DECLARE @password VARCHAR(255)
SET @password = master.sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HASHBYTES('MD5', '12290'), 1, 0)
SELECT @password
```

Yet when I run the following statement from the table:

```
SELECT ID,  master.sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), ID)), 1, 0) AS temp
FROM Clients
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

The 'temp' value matching to the 'ID' value of 12290 returns: 1867dce5f1ee1ddb46ff0ccd1fc58e03

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the conversion function you're using, but why not just do a straight comparison? It's just a string, so compare it to the hashed value you got from php?

Comment: have you tried with `VARCHAR()` instead on `NVARCHAR()` ?

Comment: Using VARCHAR() instead worked, thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have SQL server to test this on, but the CONVERT command might be creating the NVARCHAR with 240-odd trailing blanks (as you have specified NVARCHAR(255))

Try setting the NVARCHAR to the length of the ID to test:

```
ARE @password VARCHAR(255)
SET @password = master.sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), '12290')), 1, 0)
SELECT @password
```

Try with different lengths in the CONVERT - is there any difference?

Answer (score 3):

Python helped me to help you.

```
>>> from hashlib import md5
>>> md5('1\x002\x002\x009\x000\x00').digest().encode('hex')
'1867dce5f1ee1ddb46ff0ccd1fc58e03'
```

NVARCHAR is Unicode type and it seems from the above experiment that `'12990'` is stored as UTF-16LE in your database: `'1\02\09\09\00\0'`.

Assuming that the data encoding in the PHP is UTF-8 data and you don't want to change the existing data in the database, this is how you can fix your PHP script:

```
<?php
    $password = '12290';
    $hash = md5(mb_convert_encoding($password, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8')) . "\n";
    echo $hash;
?>
```

Output:

```
susam@swift:~$ php utf16le-hash.php
1867dce5f1ee1ddb46ff0ccd1fc58e03
```

In case the data in PHP is in some other encoding such as ASCII, ISO-8859-1, etc. you can change the third argument to `mb_convert_encoding` accordingly. The list of all supported encodings is available at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

Also, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Answer (score 0):

One of two things is most likely the problem:

1. Either the ID column in that row has a value not exactly equal to `'12290'` (e.g. extra whitespace)
2. Or the `CONVERT` function produces such a value

In any case, a standard debugging approach would be to use an SQL query to SELECT the string lengths of that ID field and the return value of `CONVERT`; if either is not equal to `5`, you found the error.

Alternatively you can perform a dump of the table in question including data, and look at the generated INSERT statement to see what the database says the value in that column is.